# Factory returning undefined all the time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sorry, but I'm new on AngularJS and I don't understand this behavior...

I'm trying to use a factory, But I always get an undefined response from it...

So, I have a factory called pollsData, this factory is injected in the AddDataPollController controller where I use the getPoll method from the factory, notice that I print what is returned from the factory function...

```
.controller('AddDataPollController', ['$scope', 'Restangular', '$state', '$stateParams', 'pollsData', // factory
function($scope, Restangular, $state, $stateParams, pollsData) {
  console.log(pollsData.getPoll());
.
.
.
```

Then, in the getPoll method I make a Restangular request to obtain the poll with id 192, within this same function I print what is returned from the restangular request.

```
.factory('pollsData', ['Restangular', '$state', '$stateParams',
  function(Restangular, $state, $stateParams) {

  var data = {
    polls: []
  };

  data.getPoll = function() {
    Restangular.one('polls', 192).get().then(function(poll) {
      console.log(poll);
      angular.copy(poll, data.polls);
      return poll;
    });
  };

  return data;
}])
```

Now what I don't understand is that when I print the response from the factory I see the correct data, but when I try to print what I get from the controller it only show the word undefined, **shouldn't it be printing the same object in both cases?**

[image: console]

Comment: Because when you log runs the request is still processing. It's **async**

Answer (score 0):

Your dealing with `async` logic here.  You need to either return a resolve and use the response, or return a resolve and then reference the factory data.

update to:

```
.factory('pollsData', ['$q','Restangular', '$state', '$stateParams',
  function($q Restangular, $state, $stateParams) {

  var data = {
    polls: []
  };

  data.getPoll = function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
    Restangular.one('polls', 192).get().then(function(poll) {
     console.log(poll);
     angular.copy(poll, data.polls);
     return deferred.resolve(poll);
   }, deferred.reject);
   return deferred.promise;
   };
return data;
}])
```

In your controller:

```
pollsData.getPoll().then(setData, onError);

function setData(data){
    console.log(data);
}
function onError(error){
    console.error(error);
}
```

Comment: You could use events as well through something like $scope.broadcast and $scope.on

Comment: ugh, i'm not a fan of using events for data passing.  If you were thinking about when the app bootstraps letting the system know something is available great, but in this situation i much prefer to use the deferred.